# "Save the day" (like Superman)

Tags: idiom, colloquial-language

Is anyone familiar with the English expression "save the day"?  For example, if some situation looks hopeless, you might say some hero like Superman comes and saves the day.  Also might be used in slightly more common situations or mildly as a joke, like if a party runs out of beer and someone shows up with another case..

Is there some Korean expression like this?

Comment: I guess you can say `살았다`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a natural way of translating this and would be one of those phrases that needs to be translated on a case by case basis.

For example

- You really saved the day (because you helped me finished all my work) --> 업무를 다 마쳐줘서 너무 고맙다
- You really saved the day (because you rescued the boy from the burning building) --> 자기 자신의 목숨을 바치시고 우리 아이를 구하셔써 감사합니다 (Thanking for risking your own life and rescuing our child)
- You really saved the day (because you brought beer) --> 우아 맥주까지 가져왔네, 이 술 없는 딜레마를 벗어났다!

Comment: Nitpick: "자기 자신의 목숨을 바치시고" means "*sacrificing* (your) own life", not "risking".  For "risking one's life", you could say "목숨을 걸고".

Comment: Well, I can't ask for more than that...thank you.  I had a feeling this one was going to be tough!  :)